# Retrieving Soap Header on JAXWS Server Side

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

We are trying to do a security implementation in our JAX web services and are passing the UserName and Password in the header as below.

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="Id-8zvykuwmK8yg6dxn3632nQJB" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>gears_user</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">##########</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

In the Java we are trying the retrieve the Username and the password but we are not sure how to do it as, its a part of Soap Header and we have not retrieved header information before.

```
    .....
     @Resource
WebServiceContext wsctx;


public ServiceAvailabilityResponseType inquireGeographicEligibility(ServiceAvailabilityRequestType inquireGeographicEligibilityRequest)
    throws WSException
{

     HeaderList hl=(HeaderList)wsctx.getMessageContext().get(JAXWSProperties.INBOUND_HEADER_LIST_PROPERTY);
     QName security = new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", 
            "Security");    
     Header hd = hl.get(security, false);


     QName userName = new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", 
        "Username");
     try
     {
         System.out.println(hd.readHeader());    
         System.out.println(hd.getAttribute(userName));
     }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

   }
```

We are trying to do as above and get the header elements but its not returning us the value. Any help on the way to retrieve the Username and Password will be appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can read the soap header from the `SOAPMessageContext` in a `SOAPHandler` class, then pass the values to your `@WebService` implementation via attributes in the `MessageContext`.

Whereas the `HeaderList` API is specific to the JAX-WS reference implementation, the following sample should be portable across any JAX-WS runtime.

Example:

Web service impl:

```
package org.example.sampleservice;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.HandlerChain;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "org.example.sampleservice.SampleService")
@HandlerChain(file="handlers.xml")
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext ctx;

    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        String usernameFromHeader = (String) ctx.getMessageContext().get("USERNAME");
        return "Hello, "
                + name
                + " (invoked by "
                + (usernameFromHeader == null ? "[err or no 'Security' header found]"
                        : usernameFromHeader) + ")";
    }

}
```

Handler chain XML (**handlers.xml**, a file in the same package as `SampleServiceImpl.java`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<javaee:handler-chains 
     xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <javaee:handler-chain>
    <javaee:handler>
      <javaee:handler-class>org.example.sampleservice.UsernameTokenHandler</javaee:handler-class>
    </javaee:handler>
  </javaee:handler-chain>
</javaee:handler-chains>
```

The JAX-WS handler class:

```
package org.example.sampleservice;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.Node;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeaderElement;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext.Scope;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

public class UsernameTokenHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private static final String WSSE_NS_URI = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
    private static final QName QNAME_WSSE_USERNAMETOKEN = new QName(WSSE_NS_URI, "UsernameToken");
    private static final QName QNAME_WSSE_USERNAME = new QName(WSSE_NS_URI, "Username");
    private static final QName QNAME_WSSE_PASSWORD = new QName(WSSE_NS_URI, "Password");

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

        Boolean outbound = (Boolean) context
                .get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if ((outbound != null) && (!outbound.booleanValue())) {
            handleInboundMessage(context);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void handleInboundMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        String wsseUsername = null;
        String wssePassword = null;
        try {
            SOAPHeader header = context.getMessage().getSOAPHeader();
            Iterator<?> headerElements = header.examineAllHeaderElements();
            while (headerElements.hasNext()) {
                SOAPHeaderElement headerElement = (SOAPHeaderElement) headerElements
                        .next();
                if (headerElement.getElementName().getLocalName()
                        .equals("Security")) {
                    SOAPHeaderElement securityElement = headerElement;
                    Iterator<?> it2 = securityElement.getChildElements();
                    while (it2.hasNext()) {
                        Node soapNode = (Node) it2.next();
                        if (soapNode instanceof SOAPElement) {
                            SOAPElement element = (SOAPElement) soapNode;
                            QName elementQname = element.getElementQName();
                            if (QNAME_WSSE_USERNAMETOKEN.equals(elementQname)) {
                                SOAPElement usernameTokenElement = element;
                                wsseUsername = getFirstChildElementValue(usernameTokenElement, QNAME_WSSE_USERNAME);
                                wssePassword = getFirstChildElementValue(usernameTokenElement, QNAME_WSSE_PASSWORD);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (wsseUsername != null) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                context.put("USERNAME", wsseUsername);
                context.setScope("USERNAME", Scope.APPLICATION);

                context.put("PASSWORD", wssePassword);
                context.setScope("PASSWORD", Scope.APPLICATION);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading SOAP message context: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String getFirstChildElementValue(SOAPElement soapElement, QName qNameToFind) {
        String value = null;
        Iterator<?> it = soapElement.getChildElements(qNameToFind);
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            SOAPElement element = (SOAPElement) it.next(); //use first
            value = element.getValue();
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
    }


    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but then I realized it doesn't work in every case. Now I have a validator that implements `PasswordValidationCallback.PasswordValidator`, and in this case `header.examineAllHeaderElements()` returns an empty interator, as if there wasn't any nodes in the header, `getChildElements()` does the same. Why is that? The validator somehow deletes the header from the request?

Comment: I was confused, why my project can't find `handlers.xml`. I found, that in my case it must be stored in **resources**.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `getHeaders()` method if you're getting the error "MustUnderstand headers".

```
@Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        final QName securityHeader = new QName(
                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
                "Security",
                "wsse");


        final HashSet headers = new HashSet();
        headers.add(securityHeader);

        // notify the runtime that this is handled
        return headers;
    }
```