# How do we get username and password from soap headers in java

Tags: web-services, soap

How do we get username and password from soap headers in java.
sample soap:

```
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="oracle" xmlns:wsu="schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/utility">; <wsse:Username>oracle</wsse:Username> <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">oracle</wsse:Password> <wsu:Created>2004-05-19T08:46:04Z</wsu:Created> </wsse:UsernameToken>
```

Comment: <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="oracle" 
       xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/utility">
    <wsse:Username>oracle</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">oracle</wsse:Password>
    <wsu:Created>2004-05-19T08:46:04Z</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>

Comment: Please take a look on this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487114/retreiving-soap-header-on-jaxws-server-side