# What is the best way to set ThreadLocal with Id from request messageHeader on Server side JAX-WS Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, servlet-filters, thread-local

I have a **JAX-WS Webservice** exposed to client. When Client invokes it, **messageheader** will be populated with **UserId**. I am trying to set this value in **thread local** using utility class when request comes from client and remove it before sending response back to client so It can be accessible from anywhere using that variable for that thread scope. What is the best way to implement this.Can I use **Filters on server Side** or I have to go with **Jax-Ws Handlers** to initialize this value.And also Can we remove this value before sending response with **Jax-ws handlers**.

is there any other way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by **messageheader** you mean SOAP `<Header>` (and not *HTTP header*):

If you use a [Servlet Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/index.html?javax/servlet/Filter.html), to retrieve and set a threadlocal you'll have to parse the SOAP XML yourself to access the **UserId** value.

If you use a JAX-WS handler, the SOAP is already parsed for you into an object model. If you just need to pass the **UserId** value to the web service part of the application, in your handler you can simply set the value on the [SOAPMessageContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPMessageContext.html) as is the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487114/retreiving-soap-header-on-jaxws-server-side/28520054#28520054). You can also set a thread local as you specified.  To [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#remove()) or clear the threadlocal you could either use a servlet filter or simply check the `MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY` on the `SOAPMessageContext` in your handler: if it's inbound, your handler is being invoked on the web service *request*, so you want to read the message header and set the threadlocal value. If it's outbound, your handler is being asked to handle the web service response, so you'll want to [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#remove()).

Comment: Thanks.it's from MessageHeader,Handler works in my case to get the value and set it to Threadlocal and use it in webservice code while processing that request and removing if it is out bound message. Also I  have read that JAX-WS is not a thread safe, I'm just trying to figure out how websphere process requests when it gets concurrent requests. will it create a new webservice instance for each request or it will have pool of threads or beens which can be allocated for each request.How can we confirm that that thread will be accessed by only one request at that point of time.